# Python library installation problem (through pip install)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda, spacy

I have Python 3.6.5 installed in my MacBook Pro with anaconda 5.2.0. If I try to install any library through `pip install`, I get the following error message. Could you please let me know why? In the following, I am providing an example of the `pip install spacy`.

```
$ pip install spacy
Collecting spacy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 318, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 218, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 164, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 572, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 534, in find_all_candidates
    self._package_versions(page.iter_links(), search)
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 701, in _package_versions
    for link in self._sort_links(links):
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 690, in _sort_links
    for link in links:
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 880, in iter_links
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 47, in parse
    return p.parse(doc, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 289, in parse
    self._parse(stream, False, None, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 134, in _parse
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 205, in mainLoop
    for token in self.normalizedTokens():
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 264, in normalizedTokens
    for token in self.tokenizer:
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_tokenizer.py", line 59, in __iter__
    while self.state():
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_tokenizer.py", line 243, in dataState
    data = self.stream.char()
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_inputstream.py", line 246, in char
    if not self.readChunk():
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_inputstream.py", line 265, in readChunk
    data = self.dataStream.read(chunkSize)
  File "/Users/sh0/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 499, in read
    data = self.bytebuffer + bytes(newdata,encoding='utf8')
TypeError: encoding without a string argument
```

Comment: Do you have Python in 64 bits?

Comment: Yes, it is 64 bits.

Comment: If you're using Conda, why install the libraries through pip? Were you running the pip install inside of a environment?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by running `pip list --outdated` it will show which modules are out of date, but doing so will give you the correct way to update pip if it's out of data, you should be doing `python -m pip install pip --upgrade` .

Also, you could try the install command with max verbosity enabled? (`pip install -vvv ...`).

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried `python -m pip install pip --upgrade`. It is giving me the same error message that I mentioned in my question.